# GAE Django template and swedish characters

Tags: django, google-app-engine, character-encoding

I'm trying to render templates of an html-page that contains swedish characters "åäö" but when it renders in the web browser it ends up with "�". The page renders in UTF-8.

Is there any way to workaround this or do I need to write the chars as html-code?

Also any pointers to the best support for multi-lang site?

..fredrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your template file is saved in UTF-8 format (I'm not talking about hmtl encoding but about encoding of text/html file when you save it).

In Notepad++ you can do it like that: http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/9081/notepadp.png

Comment: Now I feel like and idiot. Thanks, should been able to figure that one out. :)

Comment: No worries. I learnt it hard myself couple of years ago when I was using Polish characters: ąśćłó etc.